# Opening PDF or Doc In a winform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, pdf, documentviewer

In my c#.net application I just want to open a pdf or document in a win form.
Is it possible to open a `Pdf reader or word processor` through `winform`?

Comment: Do you want to open it in its native app (pdf viewer or MS Word) or do you want to display it in a control on your windows form?

Comment: @Derek: using native app

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
            Process mydoc= new Process();

            mydoc.StartInfo.FileName   = "path to pdf or word file c:\a.doc";

            mydoc.Start();
```

Answer (score 4):

This is probably what you are after:

```
Process.Start("myfile.pdf");
```

You can read about it in the MSDN
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could do this trick using the `WebBrowser` control:

```
 WebBrowser1.Navigate("file:///C:/file.pdf")
```